# Error: Cannot find module - Throw error server.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, next.js

I am using Nextjs +Typescript, express, node and Mongo ATLAS db.

When I run node pages/server.js, I get the following error:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985   throw err;   ^ Error: Cannot find
>   module './routes/api' Require stack:
>   - /Users/Abc/Desktop/success/pages/server.js
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>       at Object. (/Users/Abc/Desktop/success/pages/server.js:13:14)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>       at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>   '/Users/Abc/Desktop/success/pages/server.js' ] }

**pages/Server.js**

```
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const morgan=require('morgan');
const path=require('path');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const routes=require('./routes/api')
const MONGODB_URI = 'xxxx';
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI ||'mongodb://localhost/success', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose is connected');});
const newBlogPost = new BlogPost(data); //instance of the model
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use('/',routes)
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is starting at ${PORT}`));
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: `const routes=require('./routes/api.tsx')`

Comment: That solved my error, thank you :)